# API asp.net core : I have been trying to execute the Get method but i get the error code 500, how can I fix this

Tags: azure, api, asp.net-core

**THIS IS MY CODE**
This code is a Device controller that is one of the controllers I have created..

```
    // GET: api/Devices
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Device>>> GetDevice()
    {
        return await _context.Device.ToListAsync();
    }

    // GET: api/Devices/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Device>> GetDevice(Guid id)
    {
        var device = await _context.Device.FindAsync(id);

        if (device == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return device;
    }
```

Comment: Would you kindly share your full `controller class` details? We need to check how you have invocked `_context` and `Device` constructor.

Comment: If you added [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it would be easier to tell. I'm not sure, at this stage.

Answer (score -1):

I have deployed ASP.NET Core Web API and able to access the Get request, follow the below steps

- Create an ASP.NET Core API in Visual studio
- Below is the file structure

[image]

**ProductsController.cs**

- Use post method in  `ProductController.cs`  use the below

```cs
 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Product>> GetAll() => Ok(_productService.GetAll());

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public ActionResult<Product> Get(Guid id) => Ok(_productService.Get(id));
```

- Deployed the Web-app to Azure app service from visual studio

[image]

- I have tried the Get request and got the below output

[image]

- Now Goto Get ID and use the copied id there as click on **send**

[image]

- After that you will get the value with the help of ID as below

[image]